# How to reference interface from android-app-1 in android-app-2

Tags: android, maven, multi-module, android-maven-plugin

I use android-maven-plugin. I want to create the following project structure:

```
/ -- parent
/ ---- main android application
/ ---- main android application integration tests
/ ---- data access android application
/ ---- data access android application integration tests
```

In the `main android application` I have an `ItemRepository` interface, which I'd like to implement in the `data access android application`.

When I try to install `data access android application`, classes of which implement interfaces like `ItemRepository` from the "main android application", it usually results in:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/api/R;
>
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/api/HelloAndroidActivity;

and similar errors.

Here's a dependency I added into `data access android application's` `pom.xml` to reference the interface. I tried changing scope to `provided` but then it couldn't find interface.

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.sandbox</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.sandbox.mainapp</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </dependency>
```

How to fix it?

Comment: its Lcom or its com check it first.

Comment: The best practice is move your ItemRepository interface and all common code into another jar type or apklib type project, then reference it in both main and data access projects.

Comment: yorkw, I've thought of that but it also means I have to move model classes - think it's a good idea?

Comment: @midnight, The problem is an apk type project cannot reference to another apk type project, although it is probably doable with some freaky maven configuration.

Comment: Having a common referenced library is a good idea, but what's the underlying coding problem you're trying to solve here? Could the solution be achieved with two seperate apks, where your data access application is or has an Android Service?

Comment: Follow this article : http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidLibraryProjects/article.html